# How to use {this.state.feed} inside an array in React Native?

Tags: arrays, react-native, parsing, state, expo

How do I parse `this.state.feed` into `MyStories` array?

```
 state = {
    feed: {}
 }

MyStories = [{
        pic: require('../assets/images/news.jpg'), 
        title: this.state.feed,
        caption: this.state.description
}]
```

Currently, it's showing: Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

***UPDATE***

This is my code now:

```
state = {
    feed: {}
 }

MyStories = [{
        pic: require('../assets/images/news.jpg'), 
        title: Object.keys(this.state.feed).map(k => this.state.feed[k]),
        caption: 'caption'
}]
```

This is how I get my `feed`:

```
componentDidMount() {
     fetch('/* .rss url */')
     .then((response) => response.text())
     .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
     .then((rss) =>  { 
       for(let i = 0; i < rss.items.length; i++) {
         this.setState(prevState => ({
             ...prevState,
             feed: rss.items[i].title
         }))
       }
     })
    }
```

I'm getting a new error: Failed prop type: Invalid prop title`of type array supplied to Tile, expected`string``

Comment: Try `Object.keys(this.state.feed).map(k => this.state.feed[k])`

Comment: where should I put this?

Comment: Try to replace `title: this.state.feed,` with `title: Object.keys(this.state.feed).map(k => this.state.feed[k]),`

Comment: Is there another alternative? It seems to be messing with my while loop, `feed: rss.items[i].title`, `items[i]` is incremented with a while loop

Answer (score 0):

Can you to expand your example? For instance, how will the feed object typically look like? Is it a string?

If it is an object (consists of keys and values), you can iterate over it in several ways. Here is an example:
`Object.entries(*OBJECT*).forEach((k,v) => console.log('key:',k,'value:',value))`

Comment: It's an array, I keep getting this error `Failed prop type: Invalid prop `title` of type `array` supplied to `Tile`, expected `string``